# Type 'HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

I'm facing the following issue with updating the state using hooks. I want to update the todo with event.target.value, but error is raising.

> Error: I'm facing the following issue with updating the state using hooks. I want to update the todo with event.target.value, but error is raising.

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
Type 'HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
 Type 'HTMLTextAreaElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, capture, and 26 more.
 55 |             variant="filled"
 56 |             style={{ width: "30rem" }}
> 57 |             onChange={e => updateHandler(e, todo.id)}
    |                                          ^
 58 |           />
 59 |         ) : (
 60 |           <ListItemText
```

Code is as following:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";
import DoneIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Done";
import { ListItem, ListItemText, IconButton, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { TodoModel } from "../Model";

type Props = {
  todo: TodoModel;
  todos: TodoModel[];
  setTodos: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TodoModel[]>>;
};

const Todo = ({ todo, setTodos, todos }: Props) => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [editTodo, setEditTodo] = useState<string>(todo.todo);

  const markDone = (id: number) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map(todo =>
        todo.id === id ? { ...todo, isDone: !todo.isDone } : todo
      )
    );
  };

  const updateTodo = (id: number) => {
    if (!edit && !todo.isDone) {
      setEdit(!edit);
    }
  };

  const updateHandler = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    id: number
  ) => {
    setEditTodo(e.target.value);
    setTodos(prevTodos => {
      return prevTodos.map(todo =>
        todo.id === id ? { ...todo, todo: editTodo } : todo
      );
    });
  };

  const removeTodo = (id: number) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ListItem>
        {edit ? (
          <TextField
            type="string"
            value={editTodo}
            variant="filled"
            style={{ width: "30rem" }}
            onChange={e => updateHandler(e, todo.id)}
          />
        ) : (
          <ListItemText
            style={{
              color: "#f1f1ef",
              width: "30rem",
              textDecoration: `${todo.isDone ? "line-through" : "none"}`,
            }}
            primary={todo.todo}
          />
        )}

        <IconButton onClick={() => markDone(todo.id)}>
          <DoneIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={() => updateTodo(todo.id)}>
          <EditIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)}>
          <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </ListItem>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

Comment: Your `updateHandler` expects `e` to be a `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, while `@mui/material`'s `TextField` can either be a `<input>` or a `<textarea>`. Change your `updateHandler` `e` parameter to be of type `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend type for event in `updateHandler` arguments, to be `e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>`

Comment: I'm unable to update the todo on pressing enter key, how can I achieve this.

Comment: I'm not using form instead I have "div" tags, how can I update the todo on hitting the enter key only.

Comment: You just need to replace `e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` with `e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>`, in updateHandler  function.

Comment: Can I extend it to KeyboarEvent, as I want to update the state on keyPress event also i.e, when user enters the "Enter" key on keyboard.