# React&TS_Union type for HTMLInputElement and HTMLTextAreaElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typing

I've got one handler for both HTMLInputElement and HTMLTextAreaElement, now I've extended type of my handler as described here: [Type 'HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964145/type-htmlinputelement-htmltextareaelement-is-not-assignable-to-type-htmlinp).

Is there a way to do it through Discriminating Unions method?

Comment: You can make lie to typescript) making your type ***as HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement***. Example `foo(20, 'stringProp', element as HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement)`

Answer (score 0):

Discriminating Unions worked for me!!! Have no idea why it didn't worked before

```
type ChangeEventTypes =
  | ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>
  | ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  | ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>;
```